# The minimum value of matrix inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, inner-products, graph-laplacian

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle L_c,W\rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \operatorname{tr}(W)=k\\ & I > W > 0\end{array}$$

in which $L_c$ is the graph Laplacian matrix

$$L_c = \mbox{diag}(C)-C, \qquad \operatorname{rank}(L_c) = n-k$$

and both $C$ and $W$ are square and their dimensions are $n$. What is the value of $W$ to get the minimum of the inner product?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far did you get? Where are you stuck? This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question [body](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3514198/edit). Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What is $\text{diag}(C)$? Does $I > W > 0$ mean $I-W$ and $W$ are positive definite, or that the inequalities are taken element-wise? Is the matrix inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{tr}(A^\top B)$?

Comment: diag(C) is the degree matrix|a diagonal matrix where diag(i,i) is the degree of the i-th node in graph C.

Comment: I−W and W are positive definite   and   the matrix inner product ⟨A,B⟩=tr(A⊤B)

Comment: $W$ is the only optimization variable, right? What is matrix $C$?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stac)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRTPE.png)k.imgur.com/PzIAY.png

which is equal to min(H'LH), and  it can be resolved by 
   [V, D] = eig(L);
    D = diag(D);
    [~, ind] = sort(D);
    W = V(:,ind(1:k))*V(:,ind(1:k))'